# Codeigniter CI_Language extend

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, extend

### Hello stack-ers!

For the past 2 days I'v tried to extend the core Language class in CodeIgniter 2.1.3 with no luck.

So what did I do:

1. Created a class called `MY_Language` and extended it with `CI_Language`
2. Put a `__construct` function in the class and added this code

   ```
   parent::__construct();
   print_r("I've been 1337");
   exit;
   ```

Now the whole thing looks like this:

```
    class MY_Language extends CI_Language{
        function __construct(){
            parent::__construct();
            print_r("I've been 1337");
            exit;
        }
    }
```

Now this doesn't do anything when I call a controller :/

Am I doing something wrong? Or is there another approach to this?

Comment: is it located in `application/libraries/Language.php` ?

Comment: Hmm... That was the main problem! I've created that class in the `application/core/MY_Language.php`. Now it works :) ... Thanks!!!

Comment: But is there a way to override the load method? @Jeemusu

Comment: Yes, by extending `CI_Loader` class

Comment: Aaah! Now it started to work :P ... Thanks for the help!